# jquery- onclick find element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck.  I have two sets of dynamic elements with a common class (`zone` and `box`) and a dynamic class:

```
<span class="zone dynamicClass1 clickable">Text</span>
<span class="zone dynamicClass6-2 clickable">Text</span>

<div class="box dynamicClass6-2"></div>
<div class="box dynamicClass1"></div>
```

When you mouseover the `<span>` `"zone"`, I want to add a class to the `<div>` `"box"`.  Then on mouseleave I want the class to be removed.  Thus, something like:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".zone",function(){
    $(this + ".the dynamic class").find(".box.the same dynamic class").addClass("hovered");
}).on("mouseleave",".zone",function(){
    $(".box.the found dynamic class").removeClass("hovered");
});
```

The dynamic classes have to be retrieved from the hovered element and then used in finding its match, they cannot be programmed by name.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Are those dynamic classes only for identifying a corresponding `.box`? If so, it would easier for you to use a `data-*` attribute (e.g. `data-box="dynamicClass1"`)

Comment: You're really making this hard, try using something else to indentify the elements, like the index, a data attribute, anything other than some random class in the middle of the className

Comment: I am reading about these `data-` attributes.  They are new to me.  It appears that they are new in HTML5, what will they do in older browsers?  Also, an `ID` should only be used once on a page, a `class` can be used as many times as needed.  Can `data-` attributes be used anywhere needed?  Can I have a `data-` attribute in my text (`<span>`) and my image (`<div>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it setup right now, you search for the div inside the span. What you want to do is get the class and then find the according div. I would suggest moving the common class to either an id data attribute, so you can do this:

```
<span class="zone clickable" id="dynamicClass1">Text</span>
<span class="zone clickable" id="dynamicClass6-2" >Text</span>

var currentClass = $(this).attr("id");
$("div." + currentClass).addClass("hovered");
```

or this:

```
<span class="zone clickable" data-class="dynamicClass1">Text</span>
<span class="zone clickable" data-class="dynamicClass6-2" >Text</span>

var currentClass = $(this).data("class");
$("div." + currentClass).addClass("hovered");
```

See this JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/7v3hd/1/**

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion (as well as I understood it) and I was not able to get it to work.  I put it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v3hd/).  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have looked at your fiddle, and fixed it for you :) http://jsfiddle.net/7v3hd/1/

Comment: I am not familiar with the `data-` attribute.  I have been reading about it.  Why would you choose to use `data-` on the text (`<span>`) but not on the image (`div`)?

Comment: data- attribute is simply for storing data. This is an easy way finding the correct class (opposed to selecting the 2nd class you type). You don't need it on the div because you don't need the dynamicclass from the div.

Answer (score 2):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DY4v9/)

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".zone",function(){
    var $that   = $(this),
        classes = $that.attr('class'),

        // this is the meat here
        // you need to do a string manipulation
        // to get the dynamic class out of the
        // class attribute. You could also do this
        // with regex, or split.
        theDynamicClass = classes.replace('zone', '').replace('clickable', '').trim(),
        $boxWithSameClass = $(".box."+theDynamicClass);

    $boxWithSameClass.addClass("hovered");
    $that.one("mouseleave",function(){
        $boxWithSameClass.removeClass("hovered");
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated your demo with some class attributes and it seems to work fine:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DY4v9/1/).  I don't understand your comments about string manipulation.  Can you explain?

Comment: So basically, you need to get the dynamic class as a string right? So you do have it via `$(this).attr('class');`. Problem is its got more then that class inside it. Its going to be `"zone dynamicClass1 clickable"`, when you want just `"dynamicClass1"`. So you will need to get `"zone"` and `"clickable"` out of there, you do this with string manipulation. There are a ton of valid ways of manipulating `"dynamicClass1"` out of `"zone dynamicClass1 clickable"`, I just used the easiest one for me.

Comment: I see.  You used `$.replace()` to strip out the non-dynamic elements to isolate the dynamic element.  Works great.  I have upvoted your answer.  I am still learning about these `data-` attributes that were suggested by others so I haven't selected a solution, yet.  Thanks for your help and your explanation.

Comment: Correct. I also minimized dom queries to make your code more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use;

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".zone",function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

    $("div." + classes[1]).addClass("hovered");
}).on("mouseleave",".zone",function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    $("div." + classes[1]).removeClass("hovered");
});
```

HEre is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/KWMUK/1/)**

Comment: Hmm, in that case, it works. But what if the dynamic class isn't the second class in the attribute?

Comment: Yo need to construct static structure I think this is your site

Comment: Yeah, but in your answer, you haven't.

Comment: So, if I understand this, your code will always look for the second class name for the div.  Is that something that will work cross browser?  Do all browsers maintain the class order that you code?  I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Sure, it has order that you wrote